# How to make the call to service activator transactional after split

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I am using following to define my integration flow:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow pollingFlow(MessageSource<Object> jdbcMessageSource)    {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(jdbcMessageSource,
            c -> c.poller(Pollers.fixedRate(250, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                    .maxMessagesPerPoll(1)
                    .transactional()))
            .split()
            .channel(taskSourceChannel())
            .get();
}
```

I would like to make call to service activator that reads from taskSourceChannel as transactional. Also, I want to use following with my transaction.

```
@Bean
public TransactionSynchronizationFactory transactionSynchronizationFactory() {
    ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor syncProcessor
            = new ExpressionEvaluatingTransactionSynchronizationProcessor();
    syncProcessor.setAfterCommitChannel(successChannel());
    syncProcessor.setAfterRollbackChannel(failureChannel());
    return new DefaultTransactionSynchronizationFactory(syncProcessor);
}
```

The taskSourceChannel is an executor channel.

```
@Bean
public MessageChannel taskSourceChannel() {
    return new ExecutorChannel(executor());
}
```

How can I add transaction support after split while using TransactionSynchronizationFactory. I don't want to make polling transacational. The only solution I can think of is putting transactional on activator but that won't solve my problem. I would like to make it applicable to any service activator uses this channel.

Answer (score 1):

You question is not so clear, but you definitely need to consider to add transaction into the service activator. Although you don't show what is the subscriber for that `taskSourceChannel`, but you need to think do not have several subscribers on it.

Nevertheless I think your point is to apply TX into the service activator on this `taskSourceChannel` and everything after that one.

For this purpose Spring Integration provides a `TransactionHandleMessageAdvice`. See more info the Reference Manual: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/messaging-endpoints-chapter.html#tx-handle-message-advice.

The `TransactionSynchronizationFactory` is only used from the `AbstractPollingEndpoint` implementations. However you can still utilize it in your transactional context relying on the `TransactionSynchronizationManager.registerSynchronization()`.